# How do I access neighboring cell data after I use the Find method in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I'm using Powershell to search for an email address in an Excel spreadsheet. Once I find a given cell value, how do I get the next column to the right?

I know that I likely have to work with the ["address method"](http://%20https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) as described in the link, however that property refers to boolean values. The code below uses what appears to be a range

This is my first time using Powershell with Excel, and if someone can demonstrate how to take `$found`, increment the column value, and fetch the contents not only would it be a great help, but I'll ask smarter questions in the future. ;)

```
   $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Source)
    ForEach ($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Sheets)) {
        # Find Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel
        $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchText) #What
        If ($Found) {
            # Address Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel
            $BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
            #Initial Found Cell
            [pscustomobject]@{
                WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
                Column = $Found.Column
                Row =$Found.Row
                Text = $Found.Text
                Address = $BeginAddress
                Breach = $BreachValue
            }
            Do {
                $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.FindNext($Found)
                $Address = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
                If ($Address -eq $BeginAddress) {
                    BREAK
                }
                [pscustomobject]@{
                    WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
                    Column = $Found.Column
                    Row =$Found.Row
                    Text = $Found.Text
                    Address = $Address
                    Breach = $BreachValue
            }                 
            } Until ($False)
        }
        Else {
            Write-Warning "[$($WorkSheet.Name)] Nothing Found!"
        }
    }
    $workbook.close($false)
```

Comment: Use the [`Range.Offset` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel) to refer to a column to the right.

Comment: Assuming the code above works, did you try `Column = $Found.Column + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not sure why you claim that the [`Range.Address` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-address-property-excel) refers to a boolean - in fact, you are using it in reference to the `$Found` *range*, in the line `$BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)`.
2. The [`Range.Offset` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-offset-property-excel) returns a `Range` that is offset by a certain number of rows and/or columns from the specified `Range`.

So `$Found.Offset(0, 1)` is the `Range` 1 column to the right of `$Found`, and you can then access its `.Column`, `.Text`, `.Address`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you I was confused by the rightmost column in the MSFT docs that described using a `bool`.  It seems that I can use an `int` or a `bool` in the same function. It didn't occur to me that a `variant` in an excel function is analogous to a method overload until you wrote this. Thank you